# Reading Resource Text Files on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, file-management, nsfilewrapper

This is mainly an advice question, so any pointers are much appreciated.

I have a text file that I would like to draw on when filling `UITableViews`. I just don't know when I should actually read the file, or even how. Do I use `NSFileManager`, or `NSFileWrapper`, or should I roll my own? Will a Object Placeholder be needed in the Nib file?

The idea is to create an "inventory" system that utilizes a navigation-tableView-tabBar combo.

I've tried to figure out something, but after starting and restarting, I realized I should ask for help.

Specs include Xcode4, some basic understanding, and about 13 different trashed projects.

Comment: +1 for your specs! :) Could you give an overview of what you tried? You may have been on the right track.

Comment: I suggest you improve your general programming skills before stepping into iOS development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When and how you read the file will depend largely on the file size. If it is a fairly small file, then you can read it synchronously on `-(void)viewDidLoad`. If it is larger, then you will need to read it asynchronously and display an activity indicator until the read is finished. Here is a simple method for reading a text file into an `NSString`:

```
- (NSString *) getTextFromFile:(NSString *)filePath {
   return [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath usedEncoding:nil error:nil];
}
```

Comment: please, tell, if I add resource as 'textfile.txt' into project, which path I should use to open this file?

Comment: @loldop `NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"filename" ofType: @"txt"];`